# Android align button programmatically

Tags: android, position

I have an Android button on a RelativeLayout which I want to animate.
The animation is currently done with a ObjectAnimator to move the button 50dp up and down on a scroll event.

The position of the button is currently calculated programmatically with

```
height = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels
y = height - buttonheight - bottomMargin
```

My problem with this is, that the calculation works fine in the portrait mode, but as soon as I switch to landscape mode the distance between bottom and button is bigger than in portrait mode.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

Try to `convert pixels to dp` right before putting your button on the layout:

```
public static float convertPxToDp(int px, Context context) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dp = (float) ((px - 0.5f) / scale);

    return dp;
}
```

This should work!

Answer (score 0):

This is correct and obvious when you will change your orientation your height calculation value will also change as display matrics.heightPixel will return more height in case of landscape mode.

```
height = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels
```

It will return more value and accordingly it will be recalculated. If you want to just give fixed value of space between button and bottom than you have to recheck your height calculation idea.

Comment: Yes Idea suggested by AKAGAMI will work here as height will become independent of device px.

Comment: I need to calculate the x/y position by myself because I'm animating the button. Therefore I cannot use the layout_alignBottom xml element. I'm calculating the y position in the GlobalLayoutListener after the orientation has changed. But why is the calculation working for portrait and not for landscape?

Comment: Just try to convert the height which will be returned as Pixel to DP by using the formula

public static float convertPxToDp(int px, Context context) {
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dp = (float) ((px - 0.5f) / scale);

    return dp;
}


It will return the same value in both the orientation and you will have same height in both.

Comment: so convert height to dp then subtract margin and buttonheight in dp and then convert dp to px when setting y of the button?

Answer (score 0):

first try to convert pixel to dp like this :

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics ();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
    float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpHeight = outMetrics.heightPixels / density;
    float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels/density;
```

then i think you must change your algorithm in landscape mode

Comment: but why need I change the algorithm in landscape mode? I don't want to just add or subtract a fixed value

Answer (score 0):

Converting to dp did not work.

So my solution is to wrap a RelativeLayout around my button, and animate the button relative to its parent, which is fixed.

```
  <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="56dp"
                android:layout_height="85dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="56dp"
            android:layout_height="56dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```